# Setting full screen img background in CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a web page which I'd like to set full screen image right when users enter the page. I don't want it to be fixed or anything. Just at the size of the window.

Now, I also have a footer which is positioned absolutely at the bottom of the web page. Here is the styles for the footer:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    color: white;
    background: white;
    font-family: "Quicksand";
    fill: currentColor;
}

/* Footer Section */
footer {
    display: flex;    
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: $accent-color;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Now, when I try to set my full screen image like this:

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/scorpion.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The image doesn't show at all, but when I change `min-height: 100%` to `height: 100%`, The image suddenly shows up, but the footer now is at the bottom of the viewport, not the page. Here is an image that will explain this perfectly:

https://i.gyazo.com/d47e2e1fcdeaf4f8f8cab8b847c00f43.png

As you can see, the footer now jumps up and resides at the bottom of the screen.
If I change this attribute back to `min-height: 100%`, the image doesn't show at all:

https://i.gyazo.com/b3d8b941222ac16455d220f25da8bfbf.png

How can I fix this? I want the image to be full screen but also I don't want the footer to jump up from the bottom of the page. How can I combine these 2 behaviors?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this?

Comment: make absolute position also and stretch it with top/left/right/bottom

Comment: Do you want the bottom of the image showing or that part covered by footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `height: 100vh;` it will cover 100% height for all screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve the problem with `height: 100vh`